# How to send parameters in FormType for symfony3?

Tags: forms, symfony

With symfony2, when I create a form from a controller, I was able to send parameters:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    new articleType(
        $localedefault,
        $this->get('request')->getLocale(),
        $depotCat,
        $this->get('security.context')
    ),
    $article
);
```

I recovered these parameters from the constructor of my `ArticleType`.

With symfony3, I put this :

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    ArticleType::class,
    $article,
    array(
        $localedefault,
        $request->getLocale(),
        $depotCat,
        $this->get('security.authorization_checker')
    )
);
```

but this method doesn't work.

Comment: Please format your code, as it helps readability and is more likely to attract answers. I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: ok sorry,i would do better next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `configureOptions` in your class, then: `setDefault('myOption', [])`.

Upon instantiation:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    ArticleType::class,
    $article,
    array(
        'myOption'=>array(...)
    )
);
```

And then in `buildForm` you'll have a proper key in the `options` array.

Comment: in my class, how can i add this options in the function configureOptions.this function accept 'optionResolver' only

Comment: Have you tried to implement configureOptions in your ``ArticleType`` class according to the documentation? I didn't post completely working code. See the docs, then everything will look reasonable.

Comment: it's good, I understood how it works.thank you very much for your help